# How to Specify a Constraint on a Dual-Typed Generic Interface in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

In the code below (C# with .NET 8 target), I *cannot* figure out how to specify the constraint on T in the Scale() method below.  Without it, the multiply (points[i] * scale) fails. ("Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'double'.")  Is there a solution?

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace Test {

    public interface IPoint<TSelf, TBase>
        where TSelf : struct, IPoint<TSelf, TBase>
        where TBase : INumber<TBase> {
        public static abstract TSelf operator *(TSelf left, TBase right);
    }

    public struct Point2<T> : IPoint<Point2<T>, T>
        where T : INumber<T> {
        public T X;
        public T Y;
        public Point2(T x, T y) { 
            X = x; Y = y; 
        }
        public static Point2<T> operator *(Point2<T> left, T right)
            => new Point2<T>(left.X * right, left.Y * right);
    }

    public static class Test {

        public static T[] Scale<T>(T[] points, double scale)
            /* where T : IPoint<??????> */ {
            var result = new T[points.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                result[i] = points[i] * scale;
            return result;
        }

        public static Point2<double>[] UseScale() {
            Point2<double>[] points = [ new (1, 1), new (2, 2) ];
            return Scale(points, 2.0);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are scaling by a `double`, `T` should be constrained to `IPoint<T, double>`. And since `T` is used as the type argument of `IPoint`, it should also be constrained to `struct`.

```
public static T[] Scale<T>(T[] points, double scale)
    where T: struct, IPoint<T, double> {
    ...
}
```

More generally, you can take two type parameters - `TPoint` for the type of the point to scale, and `TScale` for the type of the scalar. `TScale` would be constrained to whatever constraints `TBase` has.

```
public static TPoint[] Scale<TPoint, TScale>(TPoint[] points, TScale scale)
    where TPoint: struct, IPoint<TPoint, TScale>
    where TScale: INumber<TScale> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that isn't quite what I I'm trying to do.  I'd like the Scale function to be able to scale a set of points by the underlying type the points, which the compiler *should* know.  That is, by scaling a Point2D<double> array, it knows that the underlying type is a double, and it seems I shouldn't have to explicitly state as a generic type in Scale.

Comment: @BoCoKeith Then you should add an additional type parameter, like in the second code snippet.

Comment: @BoCoKeith "and it seems I shouldn't have to explicitly state as a generic type in `Scale`"  That is your opinion. In reality, you just *have to*. There is no way around this.